# Невозможно использовать клонированную машину в VirtualBox (OpenSUSE)

Tags: opensuse, virtualbox

Я сделал клон машины и теперь, загружаясь, вижу сообщение:

```
Trying manual resume from /dev/sda1Invoking userspace resume from /dev/sda1resume: libgcrypt version: 1.5.0Trying manual resume from /dev/sda1invoking in-kernel resume from /dev/sda1Waiting for device /dev/disk/by-id/ata-VBOX_HARDDISK_.....-part2 to appear: ...Could not find /dev/disk/...-part2Want me to fall back to /dev/disk/...-part2 (Y/n)
```

Если я нажимаю 'Y', то происходит ещё одна неудачная попытка загрузки, а потом появляется строка приглашения `/bin/sh`. Если выбираю 'n', то просто тут же выходит на `/bin/sh`.

Я прочитал это: http://diggerpage.blogspot.com/2011/11/cannot-boot-opensuse-12-after-cloning.html, но я не понимаю, как получить доступ к файлам на диске, чтобы отредактировать `/etc/fstab` и `/boot/grub/menu.lst`?

Answer (score 1):

Я сталкивался с такой проблемой после переноса OpenSUSE с винчестера на SSD на ноутбуке. Пришлось править записи в `/etc/fstab` и `/boot/grub/menu.lst`. Для этого я грузился с установочного диска в режим Recovery. Хотя если получится грузануться в single-user mode - этого будет достаточно. Напоминаю, что в этот режим можно войти через GRUB (добавить -S к командной строке) или система сама в него сваливается, когда не может загрузиться. Первым шагом - нужно переделать `/etc/fstab`.  Загрузиться через GRUB можно и через LiveCD или через командную строчку. А как только получили граф. интерфейс - menu.lst всегда можно поправить до нужного состояния =)

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы получить доступ к файловой системе загрузитесь с liveCD

Comment: Попробую, но кажется я пробовал, и с него не видно ничего(